# Trying to get .xsls filename from app.post in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to get file name of excel(xlsx) from a post request and then use it to do some custom work on it.

```
app.post('/get-excel', (req, res) => {
    var files_obj = req.files;
    console.log(req.files)
    var filename = file_obj.name;
}
```

And below is the output from the console.log()

[image]

How can I grab the filename from the above object? I tried req.files.name and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

To replicate this, I just setup a sample nodejs app and added this snippet in index.js file. Also, I am passing the file from postman for now like http://localhost:5000/get-excel and adding the file in body.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work."? Make sure to describe your observation. State the actual output you get, or post the error message if you get an error. "It doesn't work" is not informative.

Answer (score 0):

this should be simple enough. You can use `req.files[0].name` to grab the first file object. if there is multiple files the logic will need to be slightly altered. but should achieve the result being looked for!

an example of this would be as follows

```js
app.post('/get-excel', (req, res) => {
    var file_obj = req.files[0];
    console.log(req.files[0])
    var filename = file_obj.name;
}
```

This will allow you to grab data about the file and the object. in turn will give the filename as one of the properties.